# Open file based on (part) word under cursor

Tags: vim

When editing PL/SQL files I look for a way to open a file based on a word under cursor and preferable jump to a certain positon.

Files are all located in same directory.

Example file app_dummy.pkb contains:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Example');
  app_package.procedure1( i_input1 => 'mmm' );
exception
  when others then raise...
end;
```

Looking for a way to open app_package.pkb (extension is known) in another buffer and move cursor to procedure1.

I know there is ctags but not all systems I work on have that available.

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking on the checkbox. This marks the question as answered &  prevents it from bumping up

Answer (score 2):

```
nmap <F2> yiw2w:split +/<C-R><C-W> <C-R>0.pkb<CR>
```

With the cursor over the package name, pressing F2 will open a new buffer containing a file named <package>.pkb and will search for the string following the . after the package name.

`yiw` - yanks the word under the cursor (the package name)
`2w` - moves the cursor two words to the right (where . counts as a word)
`:split` - splits the window
`+` - introduces a command to be executed in the new window
`/` - begins a search
`<C-R><C-W>` - inserts the word under the cursor (the procedure name)
`<C-R>0` - inserts the contents of register 0 (zero), the yank register
`.pkb` - adds the file suffix
`<CR>` - terminates and executes the :split command

Those characters are to by typed literally.  For example, `<C-R>` is the five-character sequence `<` `C` `-` `R` `>`. They are not to be replaced by a Ctrl-R when you type them.

See

```
:help :split_f
:help c_CTRL-R
:help registers
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly as long as I don't forget to set correct working directory :)